# How to change text when playing mp3 of a voice recording

Tags: actions-on-google

I have an mp3 playing the welcome message e.g. "Welcome to the app" but how do I change the text that is displayed in Google Assistant?

```
 const ssml =
   '<speak>' +
   '<audio src="https://steven96813.000webhostapp.com/audio/welcome%20to%20bowville.mp3"></audio>' +
   '</speak>';

 conv.ask(ssml);
```

Comment: You can use ssml only for your media and SimpleResponse for text. https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few good options.

One good way is to include a `<desc>` tag inside the `<audio>` tag. This text won't be spoken, but will be displayed. It might look something like this:

```
 const ssml =
   '<speak>' +
   '<audio src="https://steven96813.000webhostapp.com/audio/welcome%20to%20bowville.mp3">'+
     '<desc>Welcome to Bowville</desc>'+
   '</audio>' +
   '</speak>';
```

You could also create a [SimpleResponse](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.simpleresponse.html) object that you pass to `conv.ask()` instead of the SSML. This would take both an `speech` property, with the SSML, and a `text` property, with what should be displayed. It might look something like this:

```
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
  speech: ssml,
  text: 'Welcome to Bowville'
});
```

Comment: Thanks that does answer my question, I got it working and it was fine for 2 days then all of a sudden I'm getting this error about handler not being a function in a .js file I never edited

dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
TypeError: handler is not a function at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9) at /worker/worker.js:783:7 at /worker/worker.js:766:11 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)

Is this related the https request to download the mp3?

Comment: First, great that you had it working. If an answer helps, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Comment: The error you're showing there looks unrelated to anything you had mentioned in this question or to serving the mp3. I'd suggest starting a new StackOverflow question, showing information about how you have the webhook setup, since this looks related to the Firebase Function configuration.